# Multi Row/Column Table with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-table

I need to generate a HTML Table based on data which comes from MySQL Database. The Table is complicated so i will try to explain it here.

Data:

```
Article Name, Price, Date

Article1, 100.5, 2014-08-01
Article2, 90.0 , 2014-08-01
Article3, 80.0 , 2014-08-01

Article2, 90.0 , 2014-08-02
Article3, 80.0 , 2014-08-02

Article1, 100.5, 2014-08-03
Article3, 80.0 , 2014-08-03
```

This are the dataset which i get from Database. For everyday we get an entry of articles and their price. But it can be that an article is not available on a day. In such a case we need to set zero Price for this date. So now i have to build a horizontal table to compare the results. Some thing like this:

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Can somebody tell me how I can generate such a table with PHP/HTML?

Comment: I think you neeed to get from database all articles name on first side and all available dates on a second side. When you get this, you can check if a price is available for each couple article/date.

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer, i will give it a try. Thanks for the first.

Comment: This table is complicated? What would an uncomplicated table look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your table is violating the first normal form because you have repeating data. Look here: [Normal forms](http://www.andrewrollins.com/2009/08/11/database-normalization-first-second-and-third-normal-forms/)

A better way to create the database is to split your table into 2. First you have a table

```
Article
-----------
ID     Article name
```

and a table

```
Price
----------------
ID    fkArticle    Price     Date
```

the fkArticle is called a foreign key and is a link to the Article table. ID is a primary key and should be auto incremented. Both ID and fkArticle are the type 'int'

This is a lot better because you can avoid having a price of 0 if it the price doesn't exist. And you can extract all prices of an article like this

```
SELECT * FROM Price WHERE fkArticle = 1
```

This will get you all prices for an article with the ID=1

You can also easily get your first result by searching on date

```
SELECT * FROM Price INNER JOIN Article ON Article.ID=fkArticle WHERE Date="2014-08-01"
```

This is a much more flexible way to do it and is adhering to the Normalforms.